# Identity through foreign entities

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have a UserProject entity linking users to projects, for this I would like $projects_id and $users_id to be the the primary keys. Following the example here: http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/tutorials/composite-primary-keys.html#identity-through-foreign-entities I expected something like the following to work:

```
<?php
namespace Hoj\Entity; 
/**
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Hoj\Entity\Repository\UserProjectRepository")
 * @Table(name="users_projects")
 */
class UserProject
{

/**
 * @Id
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="userProject")
*/
private $project;

/**
 * @Id
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER", inversedBy="userProject")
*/
private $user;

public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}   

public function __set($property, $value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```

}

...however trying to build this results in an error: "No identity/primary key specified for Entity..."

My current work around (which correctly recognises the relationships) is to set the ids manually like so:

```
<?php
namespace Hoj\Entity; 
/**
 * @Entity (repositoryClass="Hoj\Entity\Repository\UserProjectRepository")
 * @Table(name="users_projects")
 */
class UserProject
{
/** @Id @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
private $users_id;

/** @Id @Column(type="integer", length=11) */
private $projects_id;

/**
 * @var Project
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Project", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="projects_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
*/
private $project;

/**
 * @var User
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @JoinColumns({
 *  @JoinColumn(name="users_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * })
*/
private $user;

public function __get($property)
{
    return $this->$property;
}   

public function __set($property, $value)
{
    $this->$property = $value;
}
```

}

The project and user tables join back like so:

```
 /**  
  * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection $userProject
  * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserProject", mappedBy="project", cascade={"persist","remove"})
  */
private $userProject;
```

Comment: Is there a particular reason to not just use a @ManyToMany? Also, is this Doctrine 2.0 or 2.1? I recall 2.1 added support for FK based identity, wherein 2.0 this would not work.

Comment: Thanks @JaniHartikainen I simplified the example - there's actually more fields on the UserProject table which is why I haven't used a many to many. Also I'm using Doctrine 2.1.

Answer (score 0):

probably this error occurs because the key you are looking for is not in the relationship ... it happens when you run many data-fixtures: import and its fixtures with ids are static ...

I had this problem too, then cleaned the entire base including sequence and see so worked.

Consider creating unittests for application so you ensure that your class is correct and so fro solving the problem.

hug